# Is Krampus really pagan?

Tags: norse, mythohistory, demons, the-devil, gods

Is Krampus really pagan in origin and not medieval Christian? A lot of people say that he is pagan and of  Norse origin. A lot of people say that he is the son of Hel who is the goddess of Helheim in Norse mythology.

But the problem here is that I can't find any reliable ancient source that specifically tells what Krampus's old Norse name is and what exactly is his role in Norse mythology. I can't find any Pre-Christian pagan source at all whether they are Greek, Norse, Celtic, Slavic, Mesopotamian, Egyptian, etc.

For example, I'm trying to find a reliable historical Viking sagas account of Krampus and what exactly is his role in Norse mythology but I can't find any.

All I'm finding are hearsays of pagan folklore and pagan legend. Another problem is that there are also other sources that say Krampus isn't really of pagan origin but is actually of modern and medieval Christian origin like this source below here. I know that it isn't a source that came from a respected scholarly source but his arguments here are very sharp, critical, and very hard to ignore. The source below is what I am talking about:

https://talesoftimesforgotten.com/2019/12/13/is-krampus-really-pagan/

Sources like these who claim that Krampus isn't really Pre-Christian pagan in origin but of modern and medieval Christian in origin make me even far more skeptical of Krampus's supposed pagan origin.

So what exactly is Krampus? Is he really Pre-Christian pagan or is he modern and medieval Christian?

Let me know your thoughts below.

Answer (score 1):

Krampus is based in the Alps of Austria and Bavaria. I am not to sure if he is norse, maybe more of a local myth. Sure he looks a bit like Faun or a devil but in the alps there are other "Schiachperchtn" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perchta) that show up in Winter to celebrate the passing of midwinter and fade away after 6th Janurary nowadays

Comment: About him dragging naughty children to Hell, is that a modern/medieval addition Christian addition? What exactly is his role in the original pre Christian pagan mythology? Was he really demonic in the original pre Christian pagan religion as he is in the original Christian version? Also, what does the benevolent female Perchta have to do with the male demonic Christian version of Krampus?